# Getting Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 while trying to use function from a header file in main.c

Tags: c, header

I have 3 files:

- main.c is to test all function in table.h
- table.c is to implement its header file.
- table.h is the header file.
  I have included table.h in main.c, but when compile, it have me this error:

> `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "_insertItem", referenced from:
>         _main in main-788b5b.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>   Quocs-MBP:A3 jarvis$`

```
#ifndef _TABLE_H
#define _TABLE_H

//---------------------------------------------------------------------        
--------
// CONSTANTS AND TYPES
//--------------------------------------------------------------------- 
--------
#ifndef _BOOL_
typedef enum BOOL { false, true } bool;
#endif
//--------------------------------------------------------------------- 
--------
// PROTOTYPES
//--------------------------------------------------------------------- 
--------

// add an element to the table
// Return TRUE if the item is in the table
// Return FALSE if the item is *not* in the table
bool insertItem( int item );
// removes the int from the table
bool removeItem( int item );
// empty the table so that we clear all memory and can start a fresh 
table
void clearTable( );
// tells us whether or not the given item is in the table
bool search( int item );
// table iterators
// Return TRUE if item was assigned
// Return FALSE if item was *not* assigned
bool firstItem( int * const item );
bool nextItem( int * const item );

#endif
```

I have test in table.c and every is normal, so I don't put it here. Below is the first part of main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "table.h"

//typedef enum BOOL { false, true } bool;                                               

// Linked list node definition                                                          
typedef struct Node node;
```

and this is where I try to use function insertItem(int Item):

```
  //TEST insertItem(int Item) function                                                  

  //Case: Insert to an empty table                                                      
  //insertItem(0);                                                                      
  if(top ==NULL){
    printf("THE TABLE IS EMPTY\n");
  }
  insertItem(10);
  print();


  return 0;
}
```

Sorry if my post is vague or unvalid, i'm new to StackOverflow. Thank you.

Comment: @MikeKinghan ooof that's **bad**. And wrong language. Quoc: you should [edit] your question and provide the *compiler commands you're running*

Comment: And, where is the *definition* for `insertItem`, the code that is

Comment: You have to compile and link both`main.c` and `table.c`, or link the two object files.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this.

```
make clean; make
```

You are trying to build for x64 with build output trash from your last x86 build. That doesn't work too good.